# Setting default font size and background color in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

How can I set the default font size and the background color in TinyMCE?

Thanks,
Eden

Answer (score 3):

You can change the css using Javascript also.

Add this to your init function:

```
oninit : "postInitWork",
```

and

```
function postInitWork() {
    tinyMCE.getInstanceById('textedit').getWin().document.body.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF66';

    var dom = tinymce.activeEditor.dom;
    var pElements = dom.select('p'); // Default scope is the editor document.

    dom.setStyle(pElements, 'color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me as well on a WordPress 3.3 blog where we can now use the built-in TinyMCE editor in plugins and themes. (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor). Once the thing was drawn, I used $(tinyMCE.getInstanceById('mytextarea').getWin().document.body).css('font-family','sans-serif'); to switch the font from serif to sans.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the content_css option?  That's mentioned in the TinyMCE FAQ here: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:FAQ#Change_default_text_color.2Feditor_background_in_TinyMCE.3F

You can specify a CSS file for your editor with this, allowing you to set things like font and background colour.

Hope this helps; thanks
Sam

(I realise that this is a very old post, just adding this for the benefit of anyone else reading since)

Answer (score 0):

[background](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=1138)

> So basicly you would copy the
>   themes/advanced/editor_ui.css to your
>   own location, edit the colors and it
>   should be ok.

```
.mceEditorArea {
    font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

[font size](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/font_size_style_values)

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    font_size_style_values : "xx-small,x-small,small,medium,large,x-large,xx-large"
});
```

anyway, google is your friend

Comment: How this helps with default font size? You showed how to set a list of available sizes.