# How to set our custom font and font size as default in TinyMCE?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, wysiwyg

How to set our custom font and font size as default in TinyMCE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting default font size and background color in TinyMCE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124619/setting-default-font-size-and-background-color-in-tinymce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be helpful for you

http://webpress.missouristate.edu/CustomizingTinyMCE.htm

Thanks,

Kanji